# boolean in vuejs becomes 1 on server

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, boolean

I am sending a value from frontend to backend and this value is a boolean. When on the server I do this

```
dd($request);
```

I can see that I receive true, for example:

```
      "displaySlug" => array:2 [
        "type" => "boolean"
        "name" => true
      ]
```

later when I loop through the array of parameters I get from page, like this:

```
dump($key .': ' . $value['name'] .'; type: '.$value['type']);
```

now it prints this:

```
"displaySlug: 1; type: boolean"
```

When I save this to DB, it also gets saved as number and not as boolean, it becomes 1.

```
$setting = new Setting(); 
$setting->key = $key; 
$setting->type = $type; 
$setting->value = $value; 
$this->settings()->save($setting); 
return true;
```

value is where boolean gets stored as 1, I'd like to store it as true even if its just a string in db

I would like it to be boolean in db. What can I do to get it boolean instead of number?

Column where I am saving it is a string column.

Comment: [Attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) would be the most elegant way I think

Comment: yeah this looks good, however it would convert everything to boolean, I am having a settings table where I store key, value and type. Inside value I can store values that are of type: string, integer and boolean. I need to be able to save true as true in db even if its just a string, I do not like it to become 1 or 0

Comment: What technique are you using for storing the value in the database? A regular Laravel model, or manual insert/update?

Comment: manually like this: 
            $setting = new Setting();
            $setting->key = $key;
            $setting->type = $type;
            $setting->value = $value;
            $this->settings()->save($setting);
            return true;

value is where boolean gets stored as 1, I'd like to store it as true even if its just a string in db

Answer (score 2):

When printing/dumping the boolean value in PHP, it gets cast to a string.

> A [boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) **TRUE** value is converted to the [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) *"1"*. [Boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) **FALSE** is converted to *""* (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between [boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) and [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) values.<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting)</sup>

You could [convert a string back to a boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting):

```
$value = (bool)$valueFromDatabase;
```

Bear in mind:

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered **FALSE**
>
> - the [boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) **FALSE** itself
> - the [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) 0 (zero)
> - the [float](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), and the [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) "0"
> - an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) with zero elements
> - the special type [NULL](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) (including unset variables)
> - [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php) objects created from empty tags<sup>[2](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)</sup>
>     Anything else is considered **truthy**.

Instead of converting to a bool explicitly, one could just use truthy/falsey coersion of strings (refer to [PHP type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose) for more information).

```
$valueFromDatabase= 0; //false 
if (!$valueFromDatabase) { //0 is falsey, negated yields truthy expression
      //action to take server-side when value is false
}
$dataForJSONOutput = array('value' => $valueFromDatabase);
//use this in Javascript code - e.g. VueJS
echo '<script type="text/javascript">var values = '.json_encode($dataForJSONOutput).'; </script>;
```

See a demonstration in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/rfbhxpMi6ahjyY7P)

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting</sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting</sub>

Comment: actually I get 1 for true and 0 for false in database column where I store them, so its not empty on false

Comment: Sure - I presume that is coming from a bit or boolean field... That works too, given the blockquote I just added

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't print boolean value as `"true"` or `"false"` but rather automatically converts it into `"1"` or `""` (empty string).

MySQL **BOOLEAN** datatype itself doesn't save boolean as `true`/`false` because it is an alias of `tinyint(1)`.

> **BOOL, BOOLEAN**
>
> These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true

Reference: [MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

There is also a gotcha in saving boolean as string in the database that php treats the value `"false"` as `true` because it's a non empty string.

```
var_dump((boolean) "FALSE");  // bool(true)

var_dump((boolean) "TRUE");   // bool(true)

var_dump((boolean) "");       // bool(false)
```

Read PHP [Types Comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for more information.

So, a safer way of handling boolean in database would be to save it as integer value of `1`/`0` in your database and use [Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) for conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a true boolean in a string. What you will have to do in your PHP is convert it to actual true and false before writing to the database. However, if your database field is set as the boolean datatype, putting 0 or 1 should work just fine.

1/0 = True/False.

But you could test in php and say: `if($var == "1" $var = true || if $var == "0" $var = false);` Then you can write `$var` to the record. Obviously, you'll want to adapt that to your code structure but  you should get the idea.